# UiTableView didSelectRowAt method not called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

i am implementing a swipe to delete action for the UiTableView, i created a table it works fine. But when i click on the item  in a table view `didSelectRowAt` is not called - its not print ing the log.

[image]

**code**

```
class ManageUsersTable: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var editView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var main_user_table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        editView.isHidden = true


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("UsersTableCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UsersTableCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected : \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        print("Delete at index : \(indexPath.row)")
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
            // delete item at indexPath
            print("Delete at index : \(indexPath.row)")
             self.editView.isHidden = false
        }
//        let edir = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit", icon : UIImage() ) { (action, indexPath) in
//            print("Edit at index : \(indexPath.row)")
//        }
//        edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
//        return [delete, edit]
        return [delete]
    }
    }
```

can some one help me to fix this tnx.

**update**

The method works when i swipe from left to right. not on item click

Comment: have you set the tableview delegate to ManageUsersTable in its storyboard/nib?

Comment: yes. i have set the delegate

Comment: Verify `userInteractionEnabled` property once.

Comment: @Buntylm: Is user interaction is diabled, I dont think OP can scroll or swipe.

Comment: no. i can scroll and swipe. i works fine

Comment: @sathya-baman : Is that all the code in your VC ??? Make sure you don't have selectRowAtIndexPath in your VC. As per apple docs didSelectRow will not call if you call selectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Are you sure that your tableview selection is single selection? and editing too

Comment: yes its a single selection..

Comment: And what did you set for editing?

Comment: no selection during editing

Comment: please check the update in question.

Comment: @SathyaBaman: I can see an issue with code in cellForRow where you are not using dequeue but that should not create this problem. I guess there is something wrong with either how the delegate is set or tableview selection is set as No Selection. In viewdidload you can check for tableview delegate. It should not be nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Do this in your viewDidLoad

```
 let tapOnScreen: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ManageDevicestable.CheckTheTime))
        tapOnScreen.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        managetable.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnScreen)
```

add selector Method

```
 func CheckTheTime() -> Void {
        print("tapped")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following list.

1) Dont forget to set the UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource

2)   Please update your viewDidLoad With

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        editView.isHidden = true

       main_user_table.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false   //UPDATE THIS LINE
    }
```

3) The default behaviour of delete swipe is as follows

a) When you swipe the cell  -> you will see a delete button.

This function is called

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        print("swipe")
    return true
}
```

b) When you click on delete button this funtion is called

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete)
        {
            print("Delete Pressed")

        }
        }
```

c) Now when you have your delete button visible and then you tap on the cell and not on the delete button itself ,the delete button will hide and no method will be called the first time.

Now delete button is hidden and you simple tap the cell . There you go, now your below function is called

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectRowAt(\(indexPath)")
    }
```

Apart from this if you want any other behaviour . Then you must customize the UITableViewCell.

If you are experiencing any other issue please recheck your implementation thoroughly.